# How to install ubuntu 14.04 dual boot

Tags: boot, windows, 14.04

i wanted to ask How to install Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot .
i have windows 8.1 pre-installed and i downloaded the Ubuntu 14.04 and i want to dual boot them . please tell me how do i do that. please do help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Backup your Windows partitions
2. Shrink the Windows partition
3. Create a bootable USB drive with Ubuntu on it
4. Turn off fast boot and Disable secure boot
5. Run the Ubuntu installer
6. Partition the empty space (created after shrinking Windows
   partition)
7. Complete the installation
8. Reboot into the Ubuntu Live image
9. Run the boot repair

   [read here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)